# Is there an O(n*m) solution for finding the maximum mean subrectangle?

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

Hello StackOverflow community,

I've been working on an algorithmic problem and was wondering if there's an O(n*m) solution that exists for it. The problem is as follows:

Given a rectangular matrix M with positive and negative numbers, with a minimum size of 2x1 or 1x2, find a rectangle S that has the largest mean of items, with the constraint that |S| <= |M|. The mean of a rectangle is calculated as the sum of its items divided by its area.

Here is the O(n*m^2) solution we've come up with, which applies a modified version of Kadane's algorithm column by column:

```
def Q2(M):
def find_max_subarray(arr):
    # Implementation of Kadane's algorithm
    max_so_far = arr[0]
    max_ending_here = arr[0]
    start, end, s = 0, 0, 0

    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if (max_ending_here + arr[i]) / (i - s + 1) >= arr[i]:
            max_ending_here += arr[i]
        else:
            max_ending_here = arr[i]
            s = i

        if max_so_far < max_ending_here:
            max_so_far = max_ending_here
            start = s
            end = i

    return max_so_far / (end - start + 1), start, end

rows, cols = len(M), len(M[0])
max_mean = float('-inf')
for left in range(cols):
    temp = [0] * rows
    for right in range(left, cols):
        for i in range(rows):
            temp[i] += M[i][right]

        mean, start, end = find_max_subarray(temp)
        if mean > max_mean and (right - left > 0 or end - start > 0):
            max_mean = mean

return max_mean
```

I was wondering if anyone knows of a method to achieve this O(n*m) time complexity,

Comment: The submatrix with the largest mean is the 1x1 submatrix that includes only the largest element.

Answer (score 2):

See **@MattTimmermans** comment for an easy and right answer

---

###### This old answer is only relevant for largest sum, and not largest mean.

It's quite likely that such an algorithm doesn't exist :
[From wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#History)

> Grenander's two-dimensional generalization can be solved in O(n<sup>3</sup>) time either by using Kadane's algorithm as a subroutine, or through a divide-and-conquer approach. Slightly faster algorithms based on distance matrix multiplication have been proposed by Tamaki & Tokuyama (1998) and by Takaoka (2002). There is some evidence that no significantly faster algorithm exists; an algorithm that solves the two-dimensional maximum subarray problem in O(n<sup>3−ε</sup>) time, for any ε>0, would imply a similarly fast algorithm for the all-pairs shortest paths problem

Comment: No matter how you partition a matrix, the mean of the whole can't be larger than the mean of all the parts.  This makes max-mean different than max-sum, and max-mean problems usually don't require something like Kadane's algorithm.

Comment: @MattTimmermans True, I failed to see that those are differents problems. I'll update my answer reflecting this. Thank you